# Installing OpenMPI on Google cloud cluster

Tags: openmpi

I would like to have OpenMPI installed on all nodes of my cluster in google cloud. So far i have been installing OpenMPI individually on each node. That is say I have 4 nodes I connect to each node and install OpenMPI in it, which is really time consuming and messy. Is there a way to install it and share it among all the cluster nodes. Or any other shorter procedure.

Any knowledge regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it but the following article explains the idea of creating an image with mpi already installed and then firing that image on as many nodes as you want:

http://www.reidatcheson.com/c/programming/hpc/mpi/cloud/2015/12/27/mpi-on-gcompute.html